# How to use EL conditional operator in JSF component attribute?

Tags: jsf, el, conditional-operator

I need to dynamically choose the width of a `<p:panelGrid>` based on a backing bean property. However it is not working for me. I have a feeling that I have some syntax error in my code.

```
<p:panelGrid style="width:#{myBean.fromCCRM} ?70%:90%">
    ...
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 13):

The entire statement needs to go inside `#{...}`.

```
style="width:#{myBean.fromCCRM ? '70%' : '90%'}"
```